# Anybody can explain this error? Couldn't match type `Integer'

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn haskell and there is a particular error that I'm not able to figure out.

```
robot (_name,_attack,_hp) = \ cmd -> cmd (_name,_attack,_hp)

hp (_,_,h) = h
getHp aRobot = aRobot hp

setHp aRobot newHp = aRobot (\ (n,a,_) -> robot (n,a,newHp))

damage aRobot amount = let actualHp = getHp aRobot
                        in
                        setHp aRobot (actualHp - amount)


makeKiller = robot ("Killer",10,200)
makeBetty = robot ("Betty",5,300)

----- Example of computation in ghci

b = makeBetty
b1 = damage b 34 

<interactive>:52:14: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Integer'
                     with `(([Char], Integer, t1) -> t0) -> t0'
      Expected type: (([Char], Integer,
                       (([Char], Integer, t1) -> t0) -> t0)
                      -> (([Char], Integer, t1) -> t0) -> t0)
                     -> t1
        Actual type: (([Char], Integer, Integer) -> t1) -> t1
    * In the first argument of damage, namely `b'
      In the expression: damage b 34
      In an equation for `b1': b1 = damage b 34
    * Relevant bindings include b1 :: t1 (bound at <interactive>:52:1)
```

There is something in the damage function that's wrong, can anyone explain the error to me please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add type signatures. For a surprise, just add a type signature to `hp`, and you will notice what type `aRobot` has in some contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code needs Rank2Types extension.

The Robot Betty has type ((String, Integer, Integer) -> t) -> t.
This type should be polymorphic type.

Function damage take Robot (Its type is (String, Integer, Integer) -> t) -> t) as argument.
Such function has rank 2 polymorhism.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

type Robot = forall t . ((String, Integer, Integer) -> t) -> t

robot :: (String, Integer, Integer) -> Robot
robot (_name,_attack,_hp) = \ cmd -> cmd (_name,_attack,_hp)

hp :: (String, Integer, Integer) -> Integer
hp (_,_,h) = h

getHp :: Robot -> Integer
getHp aRobot = aRobot hp

setHp :: Robot -> Integer -> Robot
setHp aRobot newHp = aRobot (\ (n,a,_) -> robot (n,a,newHp))

damage :: Robot -> Integer -> Robot
damage aRobot amount = let actualHp = getHp aRobot
                        in
                        setHp aRobot (actualHp - amount)


makeKiller :: Robot
makeKiller = robot ("Killer",10,200)

makeBetty :: Robot
makeBetty = robot ("Betty",5,300)
```

If no rank 2 types, the robot types which getHp and setHp requires are mismatched. Function getHp requires ((String, Integer, Integer) -> Integer) -> Integer as Robot type. And function setHp requires ((String, Integer, Integer) -> Robot) -> Robot.

Simplified version here.

```
fun :: (a -> a) -> Char -> Int -> (Char, Int)
fun f c n = (f c, f n)
```

This definition cause type error.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

fun :: (forall a . a -> a) -> Char -> Int -> (Char, Int)
fun f c n = (f c, f n)
```

This definition is OK!

Comment: Thank you!
Unfortunately there are many language features of which I'm not aware of at the moment, that's why I wasn't be able to figure out the issue.
VS code suggested me that kind of type signature, but I didn't understand why.
 I'll use your answer for future reference :)

Comment: This might be what @StefanoCerruti asked for, but I doubt it's what he needs. There is no reason Robot needs to be a function.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe he needs ADT.

Comment: I will write yet another answer.

Comment: @overactor I know that maybe is silly to use a lamba to handle state, but I'm following a book and experimenting with the examples... I'm not using/learning algebraic data type yet

Comment: @overactor Thank you.

Comment: @StefanoCerruti Is the book's example code written by Lisp?

Comment: @YoshikuniJujo it's an Haskell book. In that chapter the author claims that state can be represented and stored by functions using lamba. I don't know if it's a Lisp idiomatic form. To be fair the author used `damage aRobot amount = aRobot (\ (n,a,h) -> robot (n,a,h-amount))` to damage the robot and that function hadn't problems. I was just exploring other options

Comment: The author may try to explain CPS (continuation passing style). https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't need robot to be a function, just declare it as a type that's a tuple:

```
type Robot = (String, Integer, Integer)

getHp :: Robot -> Integer
getHp (_, _, hp) = hp

setHp :: Robot -> Integer -> Robot
setHp (name, attack, _) hp = (name, attack, hp)

damage :: Robot -> Integer -> Robot
damage r dmg = setHp r $ getHp r - dmg

makeKiller :: Robot
makeKiller = ("Killer", 10, 200)

makeBetty :: Robot
makeBetty = ("Betty", 5, 300)

b = makeBetty
b1 = damage b 34
```

Alternatively, you could make Robot an [algebraic data type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Algebraic_data_type), which would definitely be better than just using a tuple.